# Change order in a date with javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have a date like 8/9/2010 in a textbox, how can I easiest set a variable to the value 201098?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `20100908`?  Just curious...

Comment: it doesn't matter really

Comment: Yes, it does.  What's `2010123`?  December 3rd or January 23rd?

Comment: @SLaks: Perhaps it doesn't matter in Peter's case (I can't think of a good example, but I'm sure it's possible).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var date = "8/9/2010";

var result = date.split('/').reverse().join('');
```

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/hX357/

To add leading zeros to the month and day (when needed) you could do this:

```
var date = "8/9/2010";

var result = date.split('/');

for( var i = 2; i--; )
    result[i] = ("0" + result[i]).slice(-2);

result = result.reverse().join('');
```

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/hX357/2/

Comment: I thought of this, but for some reason the back of my mind told me IE didn't support *Array.prototype.reverse*.  Probably just confusing this with the other dozen Array functions that IE doesn't support. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) to process your dates.

You can do something like

```
date.toString("yyyyMMdd");
```

to get the date in the format you want

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
"8/9/2010".replace(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/,"$3$2$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a split on '/', take the last element and make it the first of a new string, the middle element becomes the middle element of the new string, and the first element becomes the last element of a new string.

It would be like this:

myString = document.getElementById('date_textbox').value;
var mySplitResult = myString.split("\");
var newString = mySplitResult[2] + mySplitResult[1] + mySplitResult[0];

This is basically the idea I think you are going for.

-Brian J. Stinar-

Dang, it looks like I was beaten to the punch...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the built-in JavaScript Date class:

```
function processDate(dStr) {
    var d = new Date(dStr);
    return d.getFullYear() + (d.getMonth() + 1) + d.getDate();
}

processDate("8/9/2010");
```

Easiest to manage and debug, certainly.